# Cyberduck replacement for SCP transfers

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, scp

Since Cyberduck uses Java, it's out for me.

Any replacement for Mavericks that is good, has similar to WinSCP functionality and has an option to try before I buy?

Comment: Just because it uses Java? What's wrong with Java? Also, if you Google "mac ftp", you should find quite a few.

Comment: I don't want FTP. I want SCP. The last CyberDuck I tried to use wanted a too old version of Java (that Apple doesn't even ship any more), and I don't have enough confidence that Oracle knows how to keep Java up to date on a Mac (they hardly can on Windows). Embedded Java is out of the box: too much of a security risk.

Comment: I'm guessing scp in the terminal is out too?

Comment: @dwightk I use scp on the command-line now on SuSE and Mac OS, ESXi and Windows through Cygwin, but it is often too clumsy. Currently I'm investigating [Midnight Commander with SCP support](http://wiki.blue-panel.com/index.php/Midnight_Commander_(en)#SCP_Client:). BTW: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I figured after seeing you tell people you don't want ftp 3 times it was a good adjustment :D

Comment: Yeah. ftp. been there done that in a previous life when you could trust the net. Been using SSH since the mid 90s last century (:

Comment: Have you tried using the Finder's Go > Connect to Server dialogue with ssh:// ?

Comment: Yes: `URLs with the type “ssh:” are not supported.`.

Comment: Why do you think Java is a security risk here? Java in the browser yes, but Java for an application? Not significantly riskier than Objective C.

Comment: @patrix go tell that to the places I work for (: Ideally I want a tool that uses the OpenSSL binaries and can be scrunitized.

Comment: Hmm: there are "recent" `mc` universal binaries for Mac OS X at http://louise.hu/poet/tag/mc/ they are at 4.8.10 now, whereas the current cross platform version is at 4.8.12 http://www.midnight-commander.org/wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I switched to Filezilla which works splendid on both Mac and Windows. 
https://filezilla-project.org

That was after I found out that the Mac OS X [Filezilla client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla_Client/) does [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) on the same servers that also perform [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy#SCP_program).

(note to self: `SFTP` is not a different form of `FTP`, it is more like a better `SCP`)

After having used Filezilla for more than a year now, I would not ever switch back to Cyberduck.

Answer (score 6):

I’ve heard only good things about [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/#).

Comment: I recommend Transmit too.

Comment: The site says only ftp and sftp. Does it do SCP too?

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers it can connect to  FTP, SFTP, Amazon S3, and WebDAV servers.

Comment: Since it does not do SCP, it is out too (see the SCP tag in my question: it is mandatory for me).

Comment: it does not do SCP.. Interarchy as Edouard mention is the best tools for SCP under OS X, I think.

Comment: @dwightk SFTP is an extension of SCP, even if it's not technically supported by your server, try it anyway. It might work. Mine did.

Comment: TRANSMIT DOESN'T SUPPORT SCP (only SFTP) and costs $45! Please add this to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Interarchy](http://nolobe.com/interarchy/) is a FTP client which provides many other protocol, including SCP and SFTP.

Comment: I'm going to try that one out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: oh yeah, I used them way back when OSX first came out but switched to Transmit for some reason. Good to know they do SCP

Answer (score 3):

Cyberduck does not support SCP (any more). See the closed ticket: [ticket 8895](https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/8895).
Try DCommander for SCP on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/) does scp and even won an Apple Design Award for best use of open source (in 2003).

**Edit:**

Downside: it is a PPC app, so doesn't work unless you are still on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Fugu hasn't been maintained for too long, but for the people that want to try: There is a fugu version 1.2.1pre1 beta of almost 3 years old that runs on Intel at  http://sourceforge.net/projects/fugussh/files/

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm cyberduck works fine in Yosemite, too.

Using Java downloaded from Oracle site.

Cyberduck DOES use SCP, i regularly use it.

Some problems seem arise on simple PFTP site (port 21) for timeouts.

Comment: thanks for the update, but since it uses Java, it still is out for me.

Comment: I'm using cyberduck 4.7.1 and don't see an option for SCP (I'm also hunting for a Mac SCP client and so far Interarchy appears to be the only advertising it).

Answer (score -1):

Cyberduck 4.4 or later requires no Java installation.

Comment: I get mixed results when trying to find out what the embedded run-time is based on. If it is Java, it is out too: minimizing attack vectors here.

Comment: https://trac.cyberduck.io/browser/tags/release-4-4-3/lib/1.7.0-u40-b30.jre/Contents/Home/release

Comment: @mtm thanks a lot. So the Java version they use is 1.7.0-u40-b30.jre from at least 9 months old.

Comment: There is no "attack vector" in an embedded runtime.